# How to set up PXE boot on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, pxe

I would like to install a linux distro on a computer using my Windows 7 Professional computer as the PXE boot server since it has the ISO file of the distro.
How to do that? I have a DHCP router.

Answer (score 1):

Use Serva http://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html or simply put the iso on a usb thumb drive with unetbootin http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/